# Is there a way to esacpe "@" in ant build

Tags: ant

I'm trying to echo a list of file names to a file with 2 @ appended as prefix 
E.g. 
@@some_filename 
@@some_filename2

Below is what I'm doing currently which works fine and outputs as expected except its done in a really dumb way.

```
<fileset id="filesref" dir="some_path" includes="**/*.txt"/>
<property name="files" refid="filesref"/>
<for list="${files}" delimiter=";" param="file" >
    <sequential>
        <echo file="somefile" message="@@@@@{file}${line.separator}" append="true"/>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Is there a way to escape @ sign so my message could prob look something like below (let's say if \ escapes)

```
<echo file="somefile" message="\@\@@{file}${line.separator}"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show a snippet of a build file that doesn't work and what goes wrong / what error you get?

Comment: @martinclayton Hey friend I've edited my post, could you take a look? Thanks

Comment: @ is escaped with itself - your build sample seems ok.  You have a typo in line.separator - is that the issue?

Comment: ... you probably want to set append="yes" in the echo task, otherwise each iteration will truncate the file.  (You'll likely need to do that once before entering the for loop too.)

Comment: @martinclayton You're right about the append and line.separator, i do have them correctly in my code, just miss-typed them here, I've edited my sample. As you mentioned @ is escaped with itself, did you mean  `<echo file="somefile" message="@@@{file}${line.separator}"/>`  would get me what I want? Cuz I had a go with this and the result output only appended 1 @ (@some_filename) instead of 2. Thanks friend.

Comment: I found 5 @'s worked for me: message="@@@@@{file}${line.separator}" - gave me two @s at the start of each line.

Comment: @martinclayton well it does work for me, I was just curious if theres other smarter way to do so in case some days in the future I'll be needing more than just 2, I don't want to be putting tons of @s in my xml lol. Anyway I guess i'll stick with this for now. Once again thank you martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to escape the @s in the antcontrib tasks where it has a special meaning (variable sigil).  You can do this to make it a bit easier on the eye:

```
<property name="prefix" value="@@" />

<for list="${files}" delimiter=";" param="file" >
  <sequential>
    <echo file="somefile" append="yes" message="${prefix}@{file}${line.separator}"/>
  </sequential>
</for>
```